# How to send { character with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to send `{` character with AutoHotkey but following script is not working.

```
<^>!b::Send,{
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{` char has special meaning so it needs to be escaped. Your code would need to look like

```
<^>!b::Send,{{}
Return
```

see [explanation here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

While @garyh provided correct answer to the question asked, it didn't actually solve the problem that made me use AutoHotkey in the first place.

In my case that was fixing Delphi 7 and RAD PHP XE2 on Windows 8.1 where using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> in editor would execute "Show breakpoints window" shortcut (defined as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) instead of writing `{` character.

Another way of emitting `{` character that does work even in above case is

```
<^>!b::Send,{Asc 0123}
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also send the `{` and other special meaning keys by using the raw option

**command:**

```
<^>!b::Sendraw, {
```

**option:**

```
<^>!b::Sendinput, {raw}{
```

Hope it helps